# GCP IAM - Discover what Resources users are accessing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, audit, google-iam

My current situation is that users have been given default roles with excessive permissions. I would like to reduce the roles to allow access to only those Resources that the user has actually accessed in the past 3 months. At this time it's enough for me to know what Resource they accessed and not necessarily what they did when using the Resource.

How can this be done ? (preferably via gcloud cli)

In AWS I was able to do this with Cloud Trail -> Event History

Comment: Please define what **accessed** means and for which resources. Google Cloud can log access that involves API calls. That limits what you can detect. I recommend that you approach the situation in the reverse. Define which resources a user needs to access and then limit their IAM permissions to meet the requirements. Some resources support multiple methods of access, some of which are outside of Google Cloud knowledge. For example, some setups involving SSH keys to access Compute Engine. Detecting that requires parsing the SSH server auth logs.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Any Dev will tell me he needs everything. So I would rather show them what they are accessing as opposed to relying on them to tell me what they need.

Comment: Rewrite your question to show an on-topic question with what you have tried and a clear problem description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After your edit. Cloud Logging does the same things as Cloud Trail + Event History. Show what you have tried and the problem. Process the logs and show what is not being recorded. Once you have details, you will be in a better situation to find a solution. Since you have not shown that work, you might not have a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a log of resources accessed by users using [Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#data-access). Data Access audit logs-- except for BigQuery Data Access audit logs-- are disabled by default because audit logs can be quite large, you must explicitly enable them.

[Policy Analyzer](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/policy-analyzer-overview) lets you find out which principals (for example, users, service accounts, groups, and domains) have what access to which Google Cloud resources based on your [IAM allow policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies). To use Policy Analyzer, you create an analysis query, specify a scope for the analysis, and then run the query.

You can use a domain restriction constraint that can be used in [organization policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-policies) to limit resource sharing based on domain. This constraint allows you to restrict the set of identities that are allowed to be used in [Identity and Access Management policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains).

Do note that the domain restriction constraint is not retroactive. Once a domain restriction is set, this limitation will apply to IAM policy changes made from that point forward, and not to any previous changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the Audit logs under Cloud Logging:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit

Though not all services on GCP support yet audit logs.
List of supported services: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services